# Singleton mixin C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton, mixins

**Summary:** How can I create a singleton mixin in C++? I am trying to avoid copying the same `get_instance()` function, the private constructor, etc. But I can't figure out a way to make this a mixin, because the static instance will be shared by everything that inherits from the mixin.

It's easy to make each derived class a singleton, but is there a way to do it without duplicating code? Thank a lot for your help, I'm stumped.

**Code:**
I am writing a program with a `Registry` class for looking up objects by name.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T>
class Registry
{
private:
  // make private so that the class can't be instantiated and must be used via get_instance
  Registry() {}
protected:
  std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<T> > name_to_object_ptr;
public:
  static Registry<T> & get_instance()
  {
    static Registry<T> instance;
    return instance;
  }
  void register_name(const std::string & name, T*obj_ptr)
  {
    assert( name_to_object_ptr.count(name) == 0 );
    name_to_object_ptr[name] = std::shared_ptr<T>(obj_ptr);
  }
  const std::shared_ptr<T> & lookup_name(const std::string & name)
  {
    assert( name_to_object_ptr.count(name) > 0 );
    return name_to_object_ptr[name];
  }
  int size() const
  {
    return name_to_object_ptr.size();
  }
};
```

My `Registry` class is a singleton; it must be a singleton (so that registered objects will not disappear).

```
class DerivedRegistryA : public Registry<int>
{
};

class DerivedRegistryB : public Registry<int>
{
};

int main()
{
  DerivedRegistryA::get_instance().register_name(std::string("one"), new int(1));
  std::cout << DerivedRegistryA::get_instance().size() << std::endl;
  DerivedRegistryA::get_instance().register_name(std::string("two"), new int(2));
  std::cout << DerivedRegistryA::get_instance().size() << std::endl;
  DerivedRegistryA::get_instance().register_name(std::string("three"), new int(3));
  std::cout << DerivedRegistryA::get_instance().size() << std::endl;

  DerivedRegistryB::get_instance().register_name(std::string("four"), new int(4));
  std::cout << DerivedRegistryB::get_instance().size() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4

**Desired output:**

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What lionbest said sounds right. Here is a related idea that is more similar to your original design.

You declare a template class that works in a way similar to a factory for `Registry` objects. I called it `RegAccess`:

```
template <typename RegType>
class RegAccess
{
public:
  static RegType & get_instance()
  {
    static RegType instance;
    return instance;
  }
};
```

To make it work, you:

- Declare `RegAccess<Registry<T> >` a friend of `Registry<T>` (to be able to do that you need to make sure it's defined someplace *before* `Registry<T>`)
- Make the constructor of `Registry` protected, rather than private (so constructors of the derived classes can use it implicitly)
- Remove the `get_instance` method from the `Registry<T>` class definition

And then your main program becomes:

```
int main()
{
  RegAccess<DerivedRegistryA>::get_instance().register_name(std::string("one"), new int(1));
  std::cout << RegAccess<DerivedRegistryA>::get_instance().size() << std::endl;
  RegAccess<DerivedRegistryA>::get_instance().register_name(std::string("two"), new int(2));
  std::cout << RegAccess<DerivedRegistryA>::get_instance().size() << std::endl;
  RegAccess<DerivedRegistryA>::get_instance().register_name(std::string("three"), new int(3));
  std::cout << RegAccess<DerivedRegistryA>::get_instance().size() << std::endl;

  RegAccess<DerivedRegistryB>::get_instance().register_name(std::string("four"), new int(4));
  std::cout << RegAccess<DerivedRegistryB>::get_instance().size() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When I tested this, it generated the desired output.

Comment: +1 Great idea-- it's essentially a singleton template wrapper rather than a mixin.

Comment: Even though I was thinking of a mixin pattern, I prefer this wrapper to a CRTP mixin, so I'm marking it as the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a mixin. You need to declare another template parameter and provide mixed class.

```
template <typename T, typename Mixie>
class Registry
{
private:
  Registry() {}
protected:
  std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<T> > name_to_object_ptr;
public:
  static Registry<T,Mixie> & get_instance()
  {
    static Registry<T,Mixie> instance;
    return instance;
  }
  ...
};
class DerivedRegistryA : public Registry<int,DerivedRegistryA>
{
};

class DerivedRegistryB : public Registry<int,DerivedRegistryB>
{
};
```

Comment: +1 Something about this smelled of CRTP! I really wish there were a way to somehow specify CRTP and automatically say one template argument is the class inheriting.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is both `DerivedRegistryA` and `DerivedRegistryB` is sharing the same `name_to_object_ptr`

`get_instance` belongs to `Registry<T>`not any `DerivedRegistry` and both `DerivedRegistry` is actually `Registry<int>` e.g. both are same type. so both are sharing the same `static` storage. as **static storage belongs to a class not to an object**.

So both are getting the same copy of `instance` which is of `Registry<T>` type.

You need to have an instance function in the derived class or somehow treat every derived class as a different type. that some how can be done by making changes in your template arguments that changes the type but doesn't alter your logic. However that will be a very bad design.

you can remove the `get_instance` from `Registry` and instead

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton{
  public:
  static T& get_instance(){
    static T& instance;
    return instance;
  }
};

class DerivedRegistryA : public Registry<int>, public Singleton<DerivedRegistryA>{

};
```

This would be a generic solution, and you can plug the `Singleton` class to all classes where you need singleton

Comment: I know what you mean-- the `static` values will be shared by all derived classes that inherit from the same template type. Is there any way to get around copying the code?

Answer (score 2):

**Mandatory note:** *Aaarrg a Singleton :x* (*)

That being said...

*Step 1:* creating a typed registry.

```
template <typename T>
class Registry {
public:
    typedef std::string Key;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> ItemPtr;

    Registry() {}

    Registry(Registry const&) = delete;
    Registry& operator=(Registry const&) = delete;

    ItemPtr find(Key) const;

    void insert(Key, ItemPtr);

private:
    typedef std::map<Key, ItemPtr> StoreType;
    StoreType _store;
}; // class Registry
```

*Step 2:* creating a tagged Singleton implementation.

```
template <typename Object, typename>
class Singleton {
public:
    static Object& GetMutableInstance() {
        static Object O;
        return O;
    }

    static Object const& GetInstance() { return GetMutableInstance(); }

private:
    Singleton() = delete;
}; // class Singleton
```

Note: the tag (second parameter) is utterly useless in the implementation itself. It is just a way to allow different instances (and thus singletons) to be created for similarly typed objects. It would be fine to provide a default.

*Step 3:* enjoying.

```
struct TypeA {};
typedef Singleton<Registry<int>, TypeA> RegistryA;

int main() {
    RegistryA::GetMutableInstance().insert("toto", std::make_shared(3));
}
```

(*) **Why a Singleton ?**

Honestly, most of the times a Singleton is about useless. Oh it certainly make thing **appear** easier. At the beginning.

A Singleton single-handly manages to cumulate the weaknesses of **global variables** (multi-threading issues, testing issues, etc..); and adds **another layer of crappiness** on top with its uniqueness enforcement (more testing issues) and generally more verbose interface (`GetInstance` hell).

You should at least get rid of the uniqueness enforcement and just provide a regular global variable (yesterday was the *Velociraptor Awareness Day*, beware they might still be lurking).

The best road, of course, would be to have just a regular object, and pass it down by reference to those functions/methods/objects that need it. Easier to track, easier to test.

Answer (score 2):

this should help to solve your problem. Be aware that this singleton is not thread safe. But you can change it if you need to.

See [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for more details.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

// simple singleton
template <class T>
class Singleton {
public:
    static T& Instance() { static T instance; return instance; }
protected:
    Singleton(){}
};

// your Registry Base
template <class T>
class Registry : public Singleton< Registry<T> > {
    friend class Singleton<Registry>;
public:
    void register_name( const std::string& name, T value ){ m_data[name] = value; }
    const T& lookup_name( const std::string& name ){ return m_data[name]; }

private:
    Registry(){}
    Registry(const Registry&){} // to prevent copies, you have to use ::Instance()

    std::map<std::string, T> m_data;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Registry<int>& instance = Registry<int>::Instance();

    instance.register_name("Value1",1);
    Registry<int>::Instance().register_name("Value2",2);

    int value = instance.lookup_name("Value1");
    std::cout << "Value1=" << value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value2=" << Registry<int>::Instance().lookup_name("Value2") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```